# Is there a command to list all syscall names and numbers on linux in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, system-calls

I know `syscall 1` means `write`,

but is there a command to list **all** implemented syscall names and numbers on linux in bash?

Comment: What manner of unportable beast are you writing?

Comment: Note that syscall numbers vary across platforms.  For example, `write` is syscall 1 for x86_64; but for 32-bit x86, syscall 1 is `exit` (`write` is 4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `man` page points to the header file `sys/syscall.h`. It has all the defined constants, and it's located at `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h`. (That's the location on OS X, which I'm using, but I think it'll be the same for most Linux distros, too.)

Comment: @lexer: if you plan to do any kind of programming then you really will need to install `man` before you go much further

Comment: I amended my answer. The man page really just points to the header file. Still, it would be good to have `man` installed, man! :)

Comment: on debian, the syscall numbers are found in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h

Comment: The "portable" `sys/syscall.h` header is, on Linux, defined with lines like `# define SYS_write __NR_write`.  The Linux-specific `asm/unistd.h` includes the right header for the current ABI (i386, x86-64, or x32), e.g. `asm/unistd_64.h` for x86-64.  It's this header that has the actual numeric constants for `__NR_write` and so on, but for portability to other Unix systems you may want to use `sys/syscall.h` and the `SYS_write` names for the constants.  For hand-written asm, in GAS syntax just `#include <sys/syscall.h>` and use the symbolic names.  For NASM, do some text processing.

Answer (score 3):

I tries @dolmen's answer, but it didn't work for me, so I did something similar like this (linux mint x86_64)

```
echo -e '#include <sys/syscall.h>' | \
cpp -dM | grep "#define __NR_.*[0-9]$" | \
cut -d' ' -f 2,3 | cut -d_ -f 4-
```

.. outputs about 500 lines like:

```
waitid 247
fdatasync 75
mq_getsetattr 245
sched_getaffinity 204
connect 42
epoll_pwait 281
init_module 175
....
```

I can create a *sed* command file with this:

```
echo -e '#include <sys/syscall.h>' | cpp -dM | grep "#define __NR_.*[0-9]$" | cut -d' ' -f 2,3 | cut -d_ -f 4- | sed 's|\(.*\) \(.*\)|s/syscall=\2 /syscall=\1 /|' > syscalls.sed
```

So I can translate those numbers from logs, like this:

```
dmesg | grep ' audit:' | sed -f syscalls.sed
```

which looks like:

```
[171511.625242] audit: type=AUDIT_AVC audit(1677790613.406:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/bin/man" pid=211339 comm="nroff" capability=1  capname="dac_override"
[173576.575868] audit: type=AUDIT_SECCOMP audit(1677847162.251:136): auid=4294967295 uid=33 gid=33 ses=4294967295 pid=200272 comm="apache2" exe="/usr/sbin/apache2" sig=31 arch=c000003e syscall=madvise compat=0 ip=0x7f5cf03eea7b code=0x80000000
[173593.434960] audit: type=AUDIT_SECCOMP audit(1677847179.107:137): auid=4294967295 uid=33 gid=33 ses=4294967295 pid=200266 comm="apache2" exe="/usr/sbin/apache2" sig=31 arch=c000003e syscall=madvise compat=0 ip=0x7f5cf03eea7b code=0x80000000
```

(it converts '28' to 'madvise')

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner that I just wrote. It works at least on Linux and requires a C compiler on the machine as it uses `/usr/bin/cpp` and system include files.

```
{ echo -e '#include <sys/syscall.h>\n#define X(c) #c c'; sed -n 's/#define \(SYS_[^ ]*\).*/X(\1)/p' $(echo -e '#include <sys/syscall.h>' | cpp | sed -n 's/# [0-9]* "\([^<"]*\)".*/\1/p') | sort -u; } | cpp -P | grep ' [0-9]*$'
```